# Update the value of an attribute in a postgresql jsonb array of objects across muliple records

Tags: python, arrays, postgresql, object, jsonb

I am trying to update a value tit in three database records that is part of a jsonb array object to change the title of gid 1 to 'newTitle Group 1' from just 'group 1' using postgresql and python.

```
create table groups (name varchar, grp jsonb)
 insert into groups (name, grp) values 
  ('joe', [{"gid": "1", "ona": "joe", "tit": "group 1 "}, {"gid": "2", "ona": "harry", "tit": "tester1 group 2"}, {"gid": "3", "ona": "moe", "tit": "group 3"}]),
  ('harry', [{"gid": "1", "ona": "joe", "tit": "group 1 "}, {"gid": "2", "ona": "harry", "tit": "tester1 group 2"}, {"gid": "3", "ona": "moe", "tit": "group 3"}])
  ('moe' , [{"gid": "1", "ona": "joe", "tit": "group 1 "}, {"gid": "2", "ona": "harry", "tit": "tester1 group 2"}, {"gid": "3", "ona": "moe", "tit": "group 3"}])
```

I want to get the result:

```
  ('joe', [{"gid": "1", "ona": "joe", "tit": "newTitle Group 1'"}, {"gid": "2", "ona": "harry", "tit": "tester1 group 2"}, {"gid": "3", "ona": "moe", "tit": "group 3"}]),
  ('harry', [{"gid": "1", "ona": "joe", "tit": "newTitle Group 1'"}, {"gid": "2", "ona": "harry", "tit": "tester1 group 2"}, {"gid": "3", "ona": "moe", "tit": "group 3"}])
  ('moe' , [{"gid": "1", "ona": "joe", "tit": "newTitle Group 1'"}, {"gid": "2", "ona": "harry", "tit": "tester1 group 2"}, {"gid": "3", "ona": "moe", "tit": "group 3"}])
```

I have not found a way to do it, please help. Seems like most of the postgresql 9.5 capabilities are for jsonb objects but not arrays of objects.

I tried to use many examples on the web but all seemed to fail. I also would consider using a where clause statement on the actual query to limit the jsonb records being searched by for example including `WHERE name IN ('harry', 'moe')` but for now just need to see how this basic update issue is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to use `REPLACE()` function including **::text** and **::jsonb** conversions within the DB, without need of any extra operation in the python code :

```
UPDATE groups
   SET grp = REPLACE(grp::text, '"tit": "group 1 "','"tit": "newTitle Group 1 "')::jsonb
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=0ba857cdbfe7392efd66b0e0a3531f6e)</kbd>

Of course, it's possibile to add a where condition such as `WHERE name IN ('harry', 'moe')` to restrict the update.

**UPDATE 1:**

If you need to perform the update for a spesific record within the jsonb object
such as

`WHERE j->>'ona' = 'joe'`, then use `jsonb_array_elements()` function within your statement as :

```
UPDATE groups AS g
   SET grp = REPLACE(grp::text, '"tit": "group 1 "','"tit": "newTitle Group 1 "')::json
 WHERE g.name IN ( SELECT g.name 
                     FROM groups AS g 
                    CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(grp) AS j 
                    WHERE j.value->>'ona' = 'joe' )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=380db7c842bd97a0081f9663b0d11d63)</kbd>

**UPDATE 2:**

If you want to find the desired value(`gid=1` *in this case*) within the jsonb column dynamically in order to derive the path, then it's possible to use `jsonb_set()` function as :

```
WITH T AS
(
 SELECT ('{'||index-1||',tit}')::text[] AS path
   FROM groups AS g2 
  CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(grp) 
   WITH ORDINALITY arr(j,index)
  WHERE j->>'gid'='1' 
)
UPDATE groups AS g
   SET grp = jsonb_set(grp,t.path,'"newTitle Group 1 "',false)
  FROM t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=0ad91a79d4f3d1c6c1f6c0e934cd4efc)</kbd>

Comment: That worked for the update, but how do I target the update so that it only updates the records based on a variable inside the jsonb for example, update only records where ona =  'joe'. Notice ona is in the jsonb array object?

Comment: hi @user3179198 , added that case too. Good luck.

Comment: what if I don't know the old tit eg 'group1 ', rather I just know to oid: 'joe' and the new tit 'newTitle Group 1 ' I want to replace the old unknown title with.

Comment: @user3179198 sorry but i couldn't understand what you wanted to explain. I think, the latest update should resolve your problem.

Comment: If I want to select by gid and just replace the tit in all groups with this gid UPDATE groups AS g
   SET grp = REPLACE(grp::text, '"tit": ""','"tit": "newTitle Group 1 "')::json
 WHERE g.name IN ( SELECT g.name 
                     FROM groups AS g 
                    CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(grp) AS j 
                    WHERE j.value->>gid' = '1' ) but I dont know the original title I dont think the replace will work ?

Comment: No, I tried [it works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=c8aedaa943858943c3b3a821cfb4843c) . Btw, I made the second demo by converting one of "ona" to "joel" which was originally "joe" .

Comment: Barbaros: Thanks for the time you are spending on this. I guess what I am trying to ask is how to us the postgresql jsonb functionality to just select one of several objects in a JsonB array to update. The selections that are made so far select the overall database record, but do not differentiate between objects in the jsonb. For example: Lets assume that there is just one database record, and the gid''s are different rather than all 1 they are 1,2,3. All I know is the gid of 1 and I want to update the tit but I don't know the old tit value. Seems REPLACE needs the old tit?

Comment: So need to use jsonb_set.   But I need the path variable and do not know how to create it.   jsonb := jsonb_set(
   ` jsonb_in          => j,
    path              => path,
    replacement       => new_number,
    create_if_missing => true); ` Am I missing something?

Comment: yes you can do @user3179198 with jsonb_set() function, you're welcome.

Comment: How to I write the call to find the path: I tried to using this reverence but did not work? https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-update-objects-inside-jsonb-arrays-with-postgresql-5c4e03be256a/

Comment: yes, it's really an elegant way to determine the desired value(try for gid=2 and 3 also) in order to update the jsonb value dynamically. Consider the **update 2** @user3179198 .

Comment: Thanks It works great, I added a where with an IN to limit the groups that are searched for the gid but all works very well!